# Find the area of a trapezoid when the base side lengths are not known

Tags: area

How would I find the area of a trapezoid if I know the lengths of the "legs" but not the lengths of the parallel sides.  So in the attached image, the lengths c and d are known but not the parallel sides, a and b.  The angle, beta, is known.  The angle between side c and a is 90 degrees as is the angle between c and b.

The only thing I have been able to think of is to draw the line, h, which will allow me to calculate a portion of the length a (h = c and d and beta are known).  However, I can't figure out how to get the other portion of the length a, which is also equal to b.

Please excuse the poor quality of the drawing.

[image]

Comment: please edit your diagram and write your attempts.

Comment: It's impossible. Sides $a,b$ can be moved like a trombone slide, preserving all the known values.

Comment: Thanks for the comment about the trombone slide.  That was very helpful.  It made me realize that I needed to take another look at the physical system that I am trying to get the area of (via the trapezoid).  After looking at it again, I realize that I can in fact separately calculate the side b.  Knowing b, everything else falls in place.  I may repost if I need help simplifying the final expression.

Answer (score 0):

If we know that the angle between side c & b and side c & a is 90 degrees, we can cut through the trapezoid to create a rectangle of side dimension b*c. So, the area for this part is b*c.

Then, the rest of the shape is a right-angled triangle which its area is (1/2)*(a-b)*c, assuming that side a is parallel to side b.

Therefore, the final area for this trapezoid is b*c+(1/2)*(a-b)*c

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: bruh... I think this is unneeded

Comment: @TatsunoriOno, you could write that the final area for the trapezoid is $$b\!\cdot\!c+\frac12\!\cdot\!\big(a-b\big)\!\cdot\!c=\frac12\!\cdot\!\big(a+b\big)\!\cdot\!c=\dfrac{(a+b)\!\cdot\!h}2$$ but the parallel sides, $a$ and $b$, are unknown.